# Calling Microsoft Azure functions from Windows Applications

Tags: c#, wpf, azure, azure-functions

How to call Azure functions on azure from a Windows Application running on local machine, without embedding the keys in the Application?

Is there a Client Proxy Generator like the one for WCF Services but for Azure functions instead? or do you just use web client ?

Comment: There are many ways to trigger a azure function, it depends on the input binding you have set up for it.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain : the only possible applicable binding seems to be http binding, but how does a local app running on windows calls an azure function?

Comment: By issuing a simple HTTP request, for example using the HttpClient class?

Comment: @mm8 : do you pass the key in clear ? what if the app is for different clients? do we just put the keys in the app?

Comment: @mm8 , looking for a sample that shows how to do this.

Comment: @Arjang if you planning to avoid storing the encryption keys as part of windows application, as others suggested you can use a normal webapi and invoke call to webapi. Web Api can forward the request to your function url. Another approach is to use Azure API Gateway in front of your azure function and access the API Gateway url from windows application.You can check this sample here for invoking function using azure api gateway. https://baskarrao.wordpress.com/2017/10/05/controlling-azure-functions-invocation-by-azure-api-management/

Comment: @Baskar : Thank you, your comment is the answer! exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling an Azure function from a .NET application is simply a matter of issuing an HTTP request to the endpoint: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/2c676980-8dd3-4112-ae41-a2c4f4825fe3/how-to-call-a-azure-function-from-aspnet-webhook?forum=AzureFunctions

The communication between Azure and the client application is encrypted using SSL.

As far as the key is concerned, you could either hard-code it into your client code or configuration or retrieve it from some service of yours.

Comment: In addition, the code key can be used in the header x-functions-key and its value (the key) can be encrypted in the appSettings of the config file.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Restsharp to access an Azure Function.
You will need to get the full Url containg the host key from the portal.
Navigate to your function in the portal.
Use the `</> Get function URL` link for the function to get the full URL (next to the Run button at top of page). The key is after "code="

```
var fullUrl = "https://myfunciton1000.azurewebsites.net/api/ResourceGroupNameExists?code=ENp/dFAluLqHM8TDr...Sk5YJ7DSEbs0PHPzTVw==";
var url = "https://myfunciton1000.azurewebsites.net/api";
var securityCode = "ENp/dFAluLqHM8TDr...YJ7DSEbs0PHPzTVw==";

var client = new RestSharp.RestClient(url);
var request = new RestSharp.RestRequest("ResourceGroupNameExists", RestSharp.Method.POST);
request.AddHeader("x-functions-key", securityCode);
request.AddQueryParameter("ResourceGroupName", "ImageStormSource");


var response = client.Execute(request);
```

Answer (score 1):

If your azure function app is using HttpTrigger it is no different than any non Azure WebAPI app. You call it via a rest client using either just basic a `HttpClient` or  a wrapper library like RestSharp.

There is nothing special you have to deal with, go find any tutorial on how to call a WebAPI app for more information.

Comment: what about the key that you need to use to call the function? do you just embed it every app? then pass it in clear in the http request?

Comment: Usually you call your function using SSL so the key is not in the clear. As for storage, yes you embed the key in your app, this is how many many Web API apps work, it is not specific to Azure Functions. One other option is change your settings on the azure function to not require a key to be passed in.

Comment: is there a sample project for this scenario?

Comment: @Arjang look at mm8's link, the accepted answer shows a simple example. you just need to replace `https://function/webhook` with whatever is given to you when you click the "[Get function URL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AlUma.png)" button when viewing the function on the azure portal.

Comment: unhelpfull response